# Using a different SIM card on iPad2 3g while travelling outside the US?

Tags: hardware, ipad, sim, cellular-data

I have an iPad2 3g with at&t.

Now, Will I be able to pop another SIM into it when I travel outside the US and use the data plan available in that country/service provider??
Is the iPad2 locked to AT&T's network just like the iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not locked and will work on any compatible network.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a site that lists all of these compatible networks?

Comment: I think that probably counts as a different question

Comment: Here is the list of the iPhone providers around the world, these should carry micro SIM cards that work with iPad too: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1937. Check for prepaid data-only plans if available. SIM cards for voice+data would work too, but you won't be able to use voice services. Other GSM operators could work too, but you would need to cut a regular sized SIM card to micro SIM size.